# Is there any valgrind command to run for more than one executables in one shot

Tags: python, valgrind

I have all executables in one folder. I want to do valgrind on that folder which will check for memory leaks on all executables in one shot. 
   command:

> valgrind --check-leak=full ./executable_name

will applicable for single executable. How to modify valgrind command to check for all executables in that folder. Please reply soon.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to have this option. I would recommend you write a shell script for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no single `valgrind` command to do it, but it's trivial to do in shell:

```
#!/bin/zsh

for exe in *(*)
do
  valgrind --log-file="${exe}.log" --leak-check=full "${exe}"
done
```